# I am getting the error that database is unknown

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Where is mistake? I try to connect to database from php script. I am getting the error that database is unknown. Database for sure exists, i can see this from PhpMyAdmin.
I use XAMPP v3.2.1 with mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev and php v5.5.9.

Script file debug1.php in folder c:\xampp\htdocs:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', $vdbname ) or die( "cannot connect to server".mysqli_error() );
```

When i run this file from browser windows using url: "localhost/debug1.php" i am getting error message:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'gintare_calendar' in C:\xampp\htdocs\debug1DBconn.php on line 5
```

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that somewhere he has $vdbname = 'gintare_calendar';

Comment: Your database has the wrong name, or you used the wrong database name 'gintare_calendar' in your script.

Comment: Are you sure, the user "root" without password have access to the database ?

Comment: @moechofe, Sure he has the right rights and password. Otherwise he would get access denied.

Comment: Can you provide a picture, with your database name, and the code where you declare $vdbname="xx";

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look for whitespace in database name. From phpMyAdmin go to database Operation sections and see if white space has been added in front or after database name.

Answer (score 1):

This means the database you want to connect to is not called "gintare_calendar".

Open your MySQL administration package (phpmyadmin) and verify the **actual name** of the database you want to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, i forget that i reinstalled XAMPP. It is true. There is no database. I have to create the database, import previous tables and than everything works again.